# How do I show an element on page load, but only the first time the user loads the page?

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

Not sure how to make this work. I am guessing I can store this as a cookie or something (I am completely unfamiliar with cookies or session tracking).

Basically, when someone visits a page, I want to load a certain DIV element (like a "Welcome to..."). But if they visit the page again later, I don't want the div to load. Even better, if they visit the page, say a couple weeks later, make the DIV element load again.

Server is running PHP (Wordpress).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies will do what you ask.  You can even set an expiration date on a cookie, which will allow your Welcome message to come up again if the user hasn't visited the site in a few weeks.

[Here's a quick tutorial on using cookies in PHP.](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp)

Comment: Good tutorial link! Quick question though - once the cookie expires, does it get deleted? Or does it just expire? Meaning, will `isset()` return false for an expired cookie?

Comment: Nevermind, I just tested it. Check out http://www.koffeebreak.info for an example of how I implemented it. Just refresh the page once it is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking of user specific, track **user** by a **field in data base** say it **Flag** for example FLAG=true for the first time and false for later visit

and

If you want to do it for **system(P.C.)** specific then only go for SESSION OR COOKIES ([**tutorial for SESSION**](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) , [**tutorial for COOKIES**](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php))

Answer (score 0):

Well, cookie could be the solution. You can learn about cookie [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp) and [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CB0QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Ffeatures.cookies.php&rct=j&q=php%20cookie&ei=fOxSTayCHsawhQeN5aGMCQ&usg=AFQjCNHRYw60ITd_JRQqeVNpbTAd_w8pQA&sig2=fxFC9pJtWLrMzkeYdseT5g&cad=rja).

But, I did this thing in a different way in one of my past project. I did something like following away:

1.Store the ip address of the user in database table.

2.after certain time i just clear those data which are old enough(i.e 7 days).

You can go with any of the solution but you should familiar with the basic staff first like session,cookie,mysql etc.

Comment: Using IP address to identify a user is generally not a very good idea. Different users sitting behind a company firewall, for example, would be identified as a single identity by this approach. Cookies are clearly the way to go with.

Comment: @András Szepesházi yes i agree with you. but cookie has its own limitation. like user can delete cookie anytime also user can disable the "cookie" option from their browser.sometime i think, why there are so many obstacles in the way of web development !?

Comment: True, cookies are not the magic all-round solution either, but most moderns websites use them to identify and track users, so I'd say it's a safe bet to go with it. As for obstacles in web developement - true again, but consider this: when you're creating a web application, it will be used by several dozen different client architectures and you have 2 billion potential users. It is bound to be complex.

Comment: @András Szepesházi you are the BOSS you are right again! Thank you for all of your kind words, those will help me to improve myself. Thanks.